Create squares buffers around globally distributed points in geographic CRS
I have a set of point features distributed globally, in geographic CRS (WGS 84). I would like to plot approximate 10*10 kilometers polygons around those, that could also be rotated. I have come out with this basic logic:

create the 10*10 km polygon centered around the point in azimuthal equidistant projection centered around each point
rotate the polygon (optional)
transform each polygon to geographic CRS.

I came up with the following expression in the Geometry by Expression builder:
transform(
    rotate(
        make_polygon(geom_from_wkt('POLYGON((-10 10, 10 10 , 10 -10, -10 -10))')),
        "rotation_angle"
    ),
    format(
        '+proj=aeqd +lat_0=%1 +lon_0=%2 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs +type=crs',
        $y,
        $x
        ),
    'EPSG:4326'
)

However, I am not quite sure the transform() function accepts custom PROJ4 strings, as the resulting polygons end up being 10*10 degrees squares centered across 0° N, 0° W. I am trying to keep the process to one step that does not involve reprojecting each point manually/individually.

You can use the following expression to make 10km squares around a layer of points from a WGS84 layer:
convex_hull(collect_geometries(
st_geodesic_transform($geometry, 1.0, 0, 5000/sqrt(2), 45+rotation, 'm'),
st_geodesic_transform($geometry, 1.0, 0, 5000/sqrt(2), 135+rotation, 'm'),
st_geodesic_transform($geometry, 1.0, 0, 5000/sqrt(2), 225+rotation, 'm'),
st_geodesic_transform($geometry, 1.0, 0, 5000/sqrt(2), 315+rotation, 'm')))

5000 is one half of the square side in meters
rotation is to be replaced by the desired rotation angle


Thanks, I'm a little worried about using EPSG:3857 considering its increasing inaccuracy  away from the equator, This is why I was hoping to work with custom projections in the expression builder...

OK I see what you are trying to do.

Yes--the points distribution can be really global, and usually quite spread across longitude, so eg. a UTM zone would not fit.

What about the updated anwser, with `st_geodesic_transform' which avoids using a local CRS for each point

Looks very interesting--you confirm st_geodesic_transform() is part of the Shape Tools plugin? I will try in a moment.

It is part of the plugin / Geometry by expression tools

Interesting, I did have to install the Shape Tools plugin to get it (which is very fine). What QGIS version do you have?

I have 3.28.0-Firenze with   Shapetools 3.4.19
